how to filter keywords from a list of keywords from the job description in excel only
I have 100 000 data. from there i gather some list of keywords. i want to find out keywords mentioned in a job description from that list of keywords in excel.
I tried to use that formula given below but didn't get accurate results.
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Product list'!$A$2:$A$98,Sheet1!H2)),'Product list'!$A$2:$A$98,""))

I had also tried this formula to search keywords as a whole word but still didn't able to get the desired results.
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&'Product list'!$A$2:$A$98&" "," "&Sheet1!H3&" ")),'Product list'!$A$2:$A$98,""))

can anyone suggest me a way to do this process in excel only so that I can filter the data in one go
Also it should not detect keywords like REST from word INTERESTED.

Post few sample data and then show your desired output.

Hey, getting these kind of matches are easier with regular expressions (than with SEARCH.) If the task needs to be done with Excel, could you please check whether you have newer features available? New Regular expression (Regex) functions in Excel. Or using Python directly (in newer versions) or via libraries.

If you have Excel 365
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, FILTER(product_list, ISNUMBER(SEARCH(product_list, job_description)), ""))


Searching for terms within word boundaries are easier with regular expressions than with SEARCH. Here's an example using simple regex in the form of \b(word1|word2)\b with REGEXTEST Function - Microsoft Support:
=LET(
    products, TOCOL(A3:A120000, 1),
    keywords, C3:C10,
    FILTER(
        products,
        REGEXTEST(
            products,
            "\b(" & TEXTJOIN("|", , keywords) & ")\b",
            1
        )
    )
)


